Looker Studio - Report download pdf shows text color in grey
Looker Studio Pro - I have made report which worked very well for last 6 months with email delivery option in pdf.
From last 2-3 days, pdf delivery shows all text in light grey color which is hard to read by users.
I also tried downloading report in pdf from looker report which shows the same (color in grey).
Anyone knows why this happened suddenly.
Tried copying same report to new one but same issue
